# Magento 2 : Assign positions to category products

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to assign positions to multiple products programmatically
using SQL queries?

with the `setPostedProducts` method it takes much time to process.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement.

Yes, you can do it via **Object Manager**.

**1. Update category products position for ALL products**

```
<?php
    /*
     * Below code used to update category of all products position 
     */
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryId = 6; //replace with your categoryId
    $newPosition = 10; //replace with your new position
    $category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryId);
    $products = $category->getProductsPosition();
    foreach ($products as $id=>$value){
        $products[$id] = $newPosition;
    }
    $category->setPostedProducts($products);
    $category->save();
?>
```

**2.Update category products position for PARTICULAR products**

```
<?php
    /*
     * Below code used to update category of particular products position 
     */
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryId = 6; //replace with your categoryId
    $newPosition = 5; //replace with your new position
    $category = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryId);
    $products = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $catProduct = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $pid = [];
    $filterName = 'sony';
    foreach($catProduct as $pro){    
         $name = $pro->getname();
         if(strpos(strtolower($name), filterName) !== false){
            $pid[] = $pro->getId();
         }
    }
    foreach ($products as $id=>$value){  
        if(in_array($id,$pid)){  
            $products[$id] = $newPosition;
        }
    }
    $category->setPostedProducts($products);
    $category->save();
    //Enable if you want to see the result
    //foreach($catProduct as $pro){   
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($pro->getData());  
    //}
?>
```

**Using Dependency Injection(DI):**

```
<?php
 
class helloWorld{
     
    protected $categoryFactory;    
    CONST CATEGORY_ID = 8;
    CONST NAME_FILTER = "sony";
     
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory      
    ){       
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;        
    }  
   /*
    * Get category object 
    */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        $categoryId = self::CATEGORY_ID;
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        return $category;
    }    
   /*
    * Get category of products collection
    */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
         
         return $this->getCategory()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
    }
    /*
    * Get category of particular products position
    */
    public function updateParticularProductPosition(){
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        $products = $category->getProductsPosition();
        $pid = [];
        $filterName = self::NAME_FILTER;
        foreach($catProduct as $pro){    
             $name = $pro->getname();
             if(strpos(strtolower($name), filterName) !== false){
                $pid[] = $pro->getId();
             }
        }
        foreach ($products as $id=>$value){  
            if(in_array($id,$pid)){  
                $products[$id] = $newPosition;
            }
        }
        $category->setPostedProducts($products);
        $category->save();
    }
     /*
    * Get category of particular products position
    */
    public function updateParticularProductPosition(){
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        $products = $category->getProductsPosition();        
        foreach ($products as $id=>$value){  
            if(in_array($id,$pid)){  
                $products[$id] = $newPosition;
            }
        }
        $category->setPostedProducts($products);
        $category->save();
    }
}
?>
```

Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used these but I face the following issues please guide me on why?
22Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Flat::saveAttribute() in /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php:122 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php(97): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver->updateUrlKey() #1 /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver->execute() #2 /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() #3 /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch() #4 /var/www/html/locostmedicalsupply_rebuide/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch() #5